# Want to redirect 301 subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to make 301 redirection for these domain.com www.domain.com ww.domain.com wvw.domain.com
To this ww1.domain.com
I have already done redirections on cloudflare by page rules domain.com, www.domain.com, ww.domain.com to ww1 but still wvw, I want to add more page rules but I see that I should pay 5 dollars per month for extra 3 page rules, I see others doing it without cloudflare I tried multiple method for adding some line on htaccess but not working. Anyone have htaccess lines for this

Here is my htaccess:

```
# Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
# généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[Image Cloudflare page rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfm0r.png)

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Comment: Why would one want to redirect all those host names?